# Understanding CI and DI in latice QCD

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-gauge-theory

What I understand about the CI and DI, is that the one quark could be connected to another quark likes. This insertion is kind of wick contractions, between the operators.

Since I do not have a very strong understanding of this insertions, I have few questions regarding the CI and DI.

[image]

In this picture the top one is connected insertion and bottom one is disconnected insertion.

[image]

The above one is the DI, where the quark like is contracting itself.

My questions are :

1. What are these black object represent?  Are they initial($t_0$) and final space point ($t_2$)? And after time evolution operator we find $t_2$. What is the big T in the second image corresponds to? Is it the total time applying the time evolution operator $U$?
2. How would you define the the quark line? From my understanding is that they are not physical, but the line between the two evolution point.
3. This author mentioned that he considered large number of lattice $16^{3} × 24$. Could you explain a bit or give me a source that I can read more regrading the reason they picked a huge number of lattice calculations. I guess they pick it because of having greater statistics.

Reference article : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.00911.pdf

Comment: The author definitely didn’t calculate on a $16^{23}\times 24$ lattice! You must mean $16^3\times 24$.

Comment: I suggest making it clear at the very beginning that CI means “connected insertion” and DI means “disconnected insertion” since this is obscure jargon,

Comment: You are right, I have updated that in the question.

Comment: There are only 98304 lattice sites. This may be large for QCD, but it isn’t a particularly large number. You always want to have as many lattice sites as possible because you are approximating continuous spacetime. This was presumably the largest lattice on which they could do the calculation in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: A link to the article you are reading might help to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks Mike, i added the article.